# How to find the boundary elements of a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Consider a matrix `m` as

```
m = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}];
```

In the matrix form this is (in my case)

[image]

Now I want to extract the boundary elements of this matrix at different levels as shown in different colors in the following image

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

If the matrix is called `A` and if `k` is the depth then

```
Join[
 A[[k, k ;; -(k + 1)]],
 A[[k ;; -(k + 1), -k]],
 A[[-k, -k ;; k + 1 ;; -1]],
 A[[-k ;; k + 1 ;; -1, k]]
 ]
```

should provide you with the elements, starting in the top left in clockwise order.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's a different solution:

```
pos[m_, {l1_, l2_}, dim_] := Position[
   CenterArray[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, {l1, l2}], 1], dim, 1],
   0
]
```

We can now specify any border using `l1` and `l2`:

```
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, m, pos[m, {2, 4}, Dimensions[m]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `{2, 4}` denotes the dimension of the matrix inside the selected border. It has two rows and four columns.

This retrieves the elements:

```
Extract[m, pos[m, {2, 4}, Dimensions[m]]]
```

Comment: It would be great if the elements can be retrieved in a cyclic order. For example, in the given case your code returns `7,4,10,6,7,1,1,1,6,3,8,0,4,6,2,7`. What I want is: `1,1,7,6,10,4,7,1,6,8,0,4,6,2,7` - starting from central right (`1`) and move anticlockwise.

Comment: @Majis I think you did the right thing by asking a [separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165938/how-to-rearrange-the-matrix-elements-in-a-special-way) about this. If I think of an answer, I'll answer there.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[layerF, layerindicesF]
layerF[dims : {_, _}, {r_, c_}] := Module[{m = Array[1 &, dims]}, 
  ArrayPad[ArrayPad[m, {{-r + 1}, {-c + 1}}], {{r - 1}, {c - 1}}] - 
  If[ArrayPad[m, {{-r}, {-c}}]==={}, 0, ArrayPad[ArrayPad[m, {{-r}, {-c}}], {{r}, {c}}]]]
layerF[dims : {_, _}, r_Integer] := layerF[dims, {r, r}]
layerindicesF[dims : {_, _}, rc_] := Position[layerF[dims, rc], 1]
```

**Examples:**

```
layerF[{10, 10}, {2, 3}] /. 1 -> Style[1, 20, Red] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
layerindicesF[{10, 10}, 3]
```

> {{3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 8}, {5, 3}, {5, 8}, {6, 3}, {6, 8}, {7, 3}, {7, 8}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8,  5}, {8, 6}, {8, 7}, {8, 8}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}];
Extract[m, layerindicesF[{10, 10}, 3]]
```

> {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 9, 3, 4, 9, 10, 2, 1, 8, 6, 5, 6, 0, 10}

```
Grid[m, Background -> {None, None, 
   Join @@ (Thread[layerindicesF[{10, 10}, #] -> {Red, Orange, Yellow, Pink, 
    LightRed}[[#]]] & /@ Range[5])}, ItemSize -> {2, 2}, 
 Dividers -> All, ItemStyle -> Directive[20, Bold]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{MatrixForm[m], MatrixForm @ MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold, 20] &,
    m layerF[Dimensions[m], 3], layerindicesF[Dimensions[m], 3]], 
  MatrixForm @ MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold, 20] &, m, layerindicesF[Dimensions[m], 3]]}, 
  Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[MatrixForm @ MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold, 20] &, m layerF[Dimensions[m], #], 
   layerindicesF[Dimensions[m], #]] & /@ {{2, 4}, {1, 3}, {3, 2}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Note: C.E.'s method using `CenterArray` is much more elegant. However, it is available only in versions v11+. The method above works in version 9.