# How to replace a selected set of elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This is a follow up on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165922/how-to-find-the-boundary-elements-of-a-matrix/165925#165925). Based on the solution provided by @C.E. I can extract the elements around the center at any level. Now I want to replace the elements colored in red (selected).

[image]

So, in the shown example, the list of the selected elements is: `{7, 4, 10, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 8, 0, 4, 6, 2, 7}` and I wish to replace them by `{6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 10, 2, 2, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 2, 8, 5}`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stuff you had:

```
pos[m_, {l1_, l2_}, dim_] := Position[CenterArray[
  ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, {l1, l2}], 1], dim, 1], 0]

m = RandomInteger[9, {10, 10}];
p = pos[m, {2, 4}, {10, 10}]
```

and then you can do

```
new = Thread[p -> {6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 10, 2, 2, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 2, 8, 5}]
ReplacePart[m, new] // MatrixForm
```