# How to rearrange the matrix elements in a special way?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This is a follow up on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165922/how-to-find-the-boundary-elements-of-a-matrix/165925#165925). 
Consider a matrix `m1` as

```
m1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
```

In `MatrixForm` it looks like

[image]

I want to rearrange the elements in a way such that it looks like

[image]

Consider another example.

```
m2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 17, 18, 19, 7}, {8, 20, 25, 21, 9}, {10, 22, 23, 24, 11}, {12, 13, 14, 15, 16}};
```

In `MatrixForm`,

[image]

And I want to transform this into

[image]

Basically, I want the boundary elements to be sorted in a counter clock-wise with the smallest element at the center-right.

How can I do this?

Comment: This could help: [Math.SE (163080)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163080/9909)

Answer (score 6):

*Update: extended to transform existing matrices.*

Building on Paul Abbott's `IntegerSpiral` code from http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Apr/msg00853.html I cobbled together a solution.  I expect that there is a cleaner way starting from scratch but this was expedient.

```
IntegerSpiral[n_Integer] :=
  Fold[Join[#, Last[#] - I^#2 Range[#2/2]] &, {0}, Range[n]] // ReIm

f1[n_?OddQ] :=
  Internal`PartitionRagged[
    Most[IntegerSpiral[2 n]] + ⌈n/2⌉, 
    Prepend[8 Range[⌈n/2⌉ - 1], 1]
  ] // MapIndexed[RotateLeft[#, #2 - 1] &] // Catenate

f2[n_?OddQ] := 
  SparseArray[Thread[f1[n] -> Reverse@Range[n^2]]]\[Transpose] // Normal

f2[old_?MatrixQ] := With[{dims = Dimensions[old]},
  Normal@SparseArray[Thread[f1[dims[[1]]] -> Reverse@Flatten[old]]]\[Transpose]
   /; Equal @@ dims && OddQ@First@dims]
```

Test:

```
Grid /@ f2 /@ {1, 3, 5} // Column
```

$\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 9 & 1 \\
 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}$

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
 8 & 20 & 19 & 18 & 2 \\
 9 & 21 & 25 & 17 & 1 \\
 10 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 16 \\
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
f2[{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}] // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{d} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
 \text{e} & \text{i} & \text{a} \\
 \text{f} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[layersF, allLayersF, spiralF]
layersF[n_?OddQ, k_] := Module[{m = Partition[Range[n^2], n]}, 
  Join[m[[k, k ;; -(k + 1)]], m[[k ;; -(k + 1), -k]], 
   m[[-k, -k ;; k + 1 ;; -1]], m[[-k ;; k + 1 ;; -1, k]], 
   If[k == (n + 1)/2, {m[[k, k]]}, {}]]]

allLayersF[n_] := layersF[n, #] & /@ Range[(n + 1)/2]
spiralF[n_?OddQ] := Partition[Range[n^2][[Ordering@Thread[Join @@ 
  MapIndexed[Reverse[RotateLeft[#, (3 n + 5)/2 - 3 #2]] &, allLayersF[n]]]]], n];
```

**Examples:**

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ spiralF /@ {3, 5, 7, 9}]
```

[image]

```
m = Partition[Array[A, 25], 5];
Row[{MatrixForm[m], MatrixForm[spiralF[Length@m] /. i_Integer :> Flatten[m][[i]]]}]
```

[image]

The function `layersF` is a modification of  [this answer by Henrik Shumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165923/125).

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Mr Wizard's I think:

```
loop[n_] := Module[{a},
  a = 1 + Accumulate @ Catenate[ConstantArray[#, n - 1] & /@ {1, 0, -1, 0}];
  Transpose[RotateRight[a, #/2] & /@ {3 n - 1, 5 n - 3}]]

loop[1] = {{1, 1}};

mat[n_] := Normal @ SparseArray[
   Catenate[Table[i + loop[n - 2 i], {i, 0, (n - 1)/2}]] -> Range[n^2]]

mat[7] // MatrixForm
```

[image]